# How to push for any branch in CircleCI?

Tags: circleci

I want CircleCI to deploy for *every* branch that pushed.

The docs (https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#deployment) state:

```
The branch field can also specify regular expressions, surrounded with / (e.g. /feature_.*/):

deployment:
  feature:
    branch: /feature_.*/
    commands:
      - ./deploy_feature.sh
```

I've tried `branch: /*/`, but this doesn't seem to work - I haven't got any builds on any branches!

I've also tried removing the `branch:` tag, but that raises a `must contain a branch or a tag` error.

Thanks for any ideas / help,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`branch: /.*/` seems to work

Although I'm not sure why

Comment: It's regex. .* is the regex for any characters.